# How can one use SparkListener callback functions?

Tags: apache-spark

How can one use SparkListener callback functions? Can we only use it for logging info?
Is there any way to accumulate sparkListener.onTaskEnd information for analysis in Spark application code?

For example..

```scala
sparkSession.sparkContext.addListener(new SomeListener)

class SomeListener {
  override def onTaskEnd(taskEnd: SparkListenerTaskEnd){

  // is there a proper/correct/valid way to accumulate this and use
  // it later in application  code?

  taskEnd.taskInfo

  }
}
```

Can we get info gathered in callback functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in context of Spark Structure Streaming. It provides event lifecycle related information which would be helpful for logging, troubleshooting etc. Below is a small implementation.

```scala
sparkSession.streams.addListener(listenStreamingQuery)

  val listenStreamingQuery: StreamingQueryListener = new StreamingQueryListener() {

    def onQueryStarted(event: QueryStartedEvent): Unit = {
      println("Query started: " + event.id + " at: " + System.currentTimeMillis)
    }

    def onQueryTerminated(event: QueryTerminatedEvent): Unit = {
      println("Query terminated: " + event.id + " at: " + System.currentTimeMillis)

    }

    def onQueryProgress(event: QueryProgressEvent): Unit = {
      val queryProgress = event.progress
      println("Query progress: " + queryProgress)
      if (queryProgress.numInputRows > 0) {
        // Implement Logging. Query the in memory table 
       val currentDf = spark.sql("select * from schema_counts order by count desc")
        
        // group them together into a single spark partition and overwrite them into a hive table.
        currentDf.repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("qa.eventlogging_valid_mixed_schema_counts")
       
        currentDf.show()
      }
      

    }
  }
```